# Do Keys in a TreeNodeCollection need to be unique?

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, treenode, treenodecollection

A `TreeNode.Name` is also the node's `key` when it part of a `TreeNodeCollection` (e.g. when added to a `TreeView.Nodes`).

Does the `TreeNode.Name` need to be unique?

I've got as far as [TreeNodeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.aspx) at MSDN but am unsure how to find the answer after that.

**Edit:**  And more importantly, what's the best way to find out this sort of answer (from within the docs / class definitions)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  The biggest hint that this is not required is that the TreeNodeCollection(key, searchAllChildren) method returns an *array* of TreeNodes.  If uniqueness were required, that method would only return a single TreeNode.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a correct procedure for finding this sort of answer?  Or do you just scan through the methods and look for hints like you suggested?

Comment: Asking a question about it at StackOverflow.com is a pretty good way.  Right after just trying it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not need to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no, they don't need to be unique.

I've debugged code where I had duplicates when I didn't want duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

No it doesnt need to be unique.  But if you wanted it to be unique to check before adding to the node, you can use the ContainsKey method;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodecollection.containskey.aspx